# CUDA: copy of a struct containing a double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, cuda, pointer-to-pointer

I have a struct which contains a double-pointer like this:

```
struct image
{
    int width, height;
    uchar** imageData;
}
```

and then

```
Image* h_imageList = (Image*)malloc(20 * sizeof(Image));
//fill h_imageList...

Image* d_imageList;
cudaMalloc(&d_imageList, 20 * sizeof(Image));
cudaMemcpy(d_imageList, h_imageList, 20 * sizeof(Image), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

when i pass `d_imageList` to a kernel as a parameter, it seems that `imageData` was not successfully copied. It is not accessible. But `width` and `height` is accessible. So what's wrong with my code? How to copy this double-pointer?

Comment: What are you expecting to be copied? The imageData pointer, or the data the imageData pointer points to? It's kind of crucial to get that sorted out. Also how do you knw the copy has not happened? 'it seems that the imageData was not successfully copied' isn't very convincing. Explain why you think the data was not copied.

Comment: Please read everything at the marked duplicate

Comment: I have tried the method given by the duplicate. When the struct contains a pointer element, it really works; when it comes to a pointer-to-pointer element, it seems to a little troublesome. Now i am trying to convert the 2D array to 1D array. THANKS A LOT!